# Bokeh hover tool works on one serie but not in combined series

Tags: python, bokeh

I have an issue with Bokeh 0.10.0. I need to plot two series of rectangles (let say a red series and a blue series), and show tool tips over them. I guess a figure will be more easy to understand:

[image]

I can't figure how to have tool-tips on all the rectangles. The following minimal example (jupyter notebook) shows tool-tips on the red series only:

```
    import bokeh
    from bokeh.charts import show, output_notebook
    from bokeh.models import HoverTool
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
    from collections import OrderedDict
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

    print('bokeh version: %s' %  bokeh.__version__)  # 0.10.0

    plot = figure(width=300, height=300, tools="hover, save")

    x_axis = [1, 2, 3]
    # length of rectangles, starting from 0
    max_ = [1, 2, 3]
    min_ = [-0.5, -1, -7]
    # middle of rectangles
    ytop = [e/2. for e in max_]
    ybot = [e/2. for e in min_]

    # first set of data (red upper rectangles)
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(sval=max_,))
    plot.rect(x=x_axis, y=ytop, width=0.8, height=max_, color="red",source=source)
    # second set of data (blue lower rectangles)
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(sval=min_,))
    plot.rect(x=x_axis, y=ybot, width=0.8, height=min_, color="navy", source=source)
    # create hover tooltips
    hover = plot.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
    hover.tooltips = OrderedDict([('X', '@x'), ('Valeur', '@sval')])
    # show in notebook    
    output_notebook()
    show(plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you are specifying a negative height, which seems to display alright, but the hit-testing for the hover tool apparently fails.

If you change your `min_` to positive values (for the `height=`) and your `ybot` to negative values, it works for me.

For example:

```
min_ = [abs(x) for x in [-0.5, -1, -2]]
ybot = [-e/2. for e in min_]
```

If negative heights should work this would be a bug, if negative heights aren't allowed it Bokeh should at least fail a bit more consistent and display some warning.

I have tested it on Bokeh 0.11.0dev9, which seems to behave similar as 0.10.

edit:
If there is at least 1 positive height in the data, all hovers are displayed correctly, also the ones with a negative height. So it only seems to fail on all negative heights.

I have create an issue on Github, see:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3517